# How much data would be remain unaffected?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

our data set has missing values. Further examination tells you that they are spread along 1.5 standard deviation from the median with distribution mean = 0 & variance = 5. How much data would remain unaffected (Tell us the %). Why?✱